# Efficiently evaluate polynomial of 80 variables with 80,000 terms

Tags: python-2.7, sympy, polynomials

I have a CSV file of 80 features (columns) and 4000 instances (rows). I want to convert this file to higher dimension (kernel 3). The new file should have 88560 columns and 4000 rows. I am trying to do a pilot with only 3 values. I have first prepared the header with symbol a,b,c and then trying to put values but unable to replace the string with values. The code is given below.

```
import csv

fw = open('polyexp.csv', "w")
a,b,c= sympy.symbols("a b c")
formula = (a+b+c) ** 3
poly = str(formula.expand())
ls = poly.split('+')
print >> fw, ls
value1 = ls[0]
value2 = ls[1]
value3 = ls[3]
a= 1
b=2
c =3

print value1,value2,value3
```

---

This gives output `a**3   3*a**2*b   3*a*b**2` instead of `1 6 12`.

### Is there any other direction to proceed please!

I am posting my revised code which is working but is there any elegant way to do this, specially the parts 1) converting 80 features to symbols 2) substituting their values which is now hard coded

```
import csv, sympy
import sympy as sym

fw = open('polyexp.csv', "w")
fr = open('polyval.csv', "r")
a,b,c, d, e= sympy.symbols("a b c d e")
formula = (a+b+c+d+e) ** 3
poly = str(formula.expand())
ls = poly.split('+')

for i in range(len(ls)):
    ls_val[i] = sym.sympify(ls[i])
for line in fr:
    tup = line.split(",")
    csvrow = list()     
    for key in range(len(ls_val)): 
        new = ls_val[key].subs([(a, tup[0]),(b,tup[1]),(c,tup[2]),(d,tup[3]),(e,tup[4])])
        csvrow.append(new)
    print >> fw, csvrow
```

Comment: It's always good to wait 1-2 days before accepting an answer; especially when your question is not yet fully answered. That way, more people will continue to look into it. But don't worry, I'll update my answer in the next 12-20 hours.

Comment: I shall follow your suggestions. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `value1,value2,value3` are just strings because you did `str(formula.expand())`. You need to make sympy expressions from them again:

```
value1 = sympify(ls[0])
value2 = sympify(ls[1])
value3 = sympify(ls[3])
```

Then, you can substitute the symbols in them with your actual values to get a numeric result:

```
print value1.subs([(a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3)])
print value2.subs([(a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3)])
print value3.subs([(a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3)])
```

Do not assign the values `1, 2, 3` to your symbols `a, b, c` like this: `a = 1`. That way you lose the symbol and `a` becomes an integer `1` rather than a symbol with that value.

See also the [tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/basic_operations.html).

---

Here's a version that generates 80 symbols, but still rather slowly.
It uses [`sympy.lambdify()`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html?highlight=lambdify#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) to be ~50x faster than `subs()/evalf()`, according to the docs.

```
import sympy as sym

fw = open('polyexp.csv', "w")
fr = open('polyval.csv', "r")
flabel = open('polylabel.csv', "r")
N = 80
symbolnames = ['a'+str(i) for i in range(N)]
symbols = [sym.Symbol(name) for name in symbolnames]  # Generate symbols 'a0', 'a1', ...
formula = sym.Add(*symbols) ** 3
poly = str(formula.expand())
terms = [sym.sympify(term) for term in poly.split('+')]
funcs = [sym.lambdify(symbolnames, term, 'math') for term in terms]

for line in fr:
    label = flabel.readline().rstrip()
    values = [float(s) for s in line.split(",")]
    csvrow = [func(*values) for func in funcs]
    print >> fw, label + ',' + ','.join(map(str, csvrow)
```

---

Finally, here's a very fast version using numpy where one invocation of the lambda function calculates a whole column of the output file. Because of this column-wise processing, the whole result array must be held in memory before writing it out. If you don't have enough memory for that, you could write out the result columns as rows, giving you a transposed output file.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

fw = open('polyexp.csv', "w")
flabel = open('polylabel.csv', "r")
N = 80
symbolnames = ['a{:02}'.format(i) for i in range(N)]

# Try to read polynomial expansion from cache file (saves time).
polycachefile = 'poly{}.txt'.format(N)
poly = ''
try:
    with open(polycachefile) as f:
        poly = f.readline().strip()
except IOError:
    poly = ''

if poly.count('+') > 0:
    # Use cached polynomial expansion.
else:
    # Calculate and save polynomial expansion.
    symbols = [sym.Symbol(name) for name in symbolnames]
    formula = sym.Add(*symbols) ** 3
    poly = str(formula.expand())
    with open(polycachefile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(poly)

terms = poly.split('+')
# Read input file into val.
val = np.genfromtxt('polyval.csv', delimiter=',', \
                    autostrip=True, dtype=np.float32)  # <-- adjust data type (i.e. precision) for calculations here!
nrows, ncols = val.shape
assert ncols == N
# Prepare efficient access to columns of val.
columns = val.T[:, :]
colsbyname = dict(zip(symbolnames, columns))
symbolnamesset = set(symbolnames)
# Create result array.
exp = np.zeros([nrows, len(terms)], dtype=val.dtype)

# Calculate result, column by column.
for i, term in enumerate(terms):
    term = term.strip()
    subterms = set(term.split('*'))
    usedsyms = subterms & symbolnamesset

    func = sym.lambdify(usedsyms, term, 'math')
    exp[:, i] = func(*(colsbyname[s] for s in usedsyms))

# Write result file.
rowfmt = ','.join(['%.7g'] * len(terms))  # <-- adjust output precision here!
for row in exp:
    label = flabel.readline().rstrip()
    print >> fw, label + ',' + rowfmt % tuple(row)
fw.close()
```

Performance: On my Core i3, the calculations take 35 seconds, and writing the result file takes 8 minutes for 17-digit precision (or 3 minutes for 7 digits).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: The program is working but slow, I had tried for 52 features but aborted after 4 hours.

Comment: @ARoy I'll look into the slowness, but it looks *very* slow and I don't know sympy very well. I recommend you unaccept my answer so that someone more knowledgable may chime in. Also, can you give a ballpark figure of what speed you need (e.g. < 2 secs/row)?

Comment: It seems that evaluating the terms with `.subs()` is too slow. But the docs [also say](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html) you'll get a 5000x speedup by using Theano or lambdify-numpy. I reckon that would be the way to go.

Comment: @ARoy I updated my answer. It's a bit faster now, but I doubt it'll be enough. If you set `N` to be smaller than the number of columns in your file, insert `values = values[0:N]` after the `values = [...]` line.

Comment: I have unaccepted the answer as per your recommendation and let us see if anyone wants to join, else I will accept the same after sometime. It would be nice to have a speed in the range of  0.5 - 1 sec / row.

Comment: The program is now working fast. I tried with 59 features and 3689 rows but the size of the CSV is 663,984 kb which is unexpected for 35990 X 3689 csv file. I am not able to open in notepad++ to check the content. I shall check with a smaller feature size and update.

Comment: @ARoy I find a file size of 663MB plausible. A number like "1.23" takes 5 bytes including the field separator, and 35990*3689*5=663M. To view the file partially, you can use [Fhred](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/) or `head -n 10 polyexp.csv` on linux/cygwin.

Comment: The first and the last column of the file is having '[' which I could not remove by different file writing, any general check would make the file writing slow. Any hint please!

Comment: @ARoy Just replace `print >> fw, csvrow` with `print >> fw, ','.join(map(str, csvrow))` or `print >> fw, ','.join(str(v) for v in csvrow)`.

Comment: I can use numpy and I shall try this one. May be the last requirement in this thread, I need to add one column in the final file which is fixed and to be read from another file. Can I join directly in this command reading from another file of one column (say polylabel.csv)

Comment: @ARoy I updated my answer to include your polylabel.csv suggestion.

Comment: @ARoy I added a numpy-enabled version to my answer. That one's really fast: 8 minutes. 90% of that is disk-writing, though :-)